# Values that covers central 50 percent of the area under the normal distribution curve

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Question:
**In a normal distribution with mean 50 and variance 100, what are the values that covers central 50 percent of the area under the curve?**

In the textbook they have solved the problem in this way:

> P(-k1<Z<k2)=0.5
> Because of symmetry, k1=k2=k.
> Hence, P(-k1<Z<k2)=2P(Z<k)=0.5
> ....

How P(-k1<Z<k2)=2P(Z<k)?

Shouldn't it be like this?:

P(-k1<Z<k2)

=P(Z<k2)-P(Z<-k1)

=P(Z<k2)-P(Z>k1)

=P(Z<k2)-[1-P(Z<k1)]

=2P(Z<k)-1

Hence, 2P(Z<k)=1.5

Please help me to clarify my confusion.

Comment: In R, code `qnorm(c(.025,.975), 50, 10)` returns
$30.40036$ and $69.59964,$ the 25th and 75th percentiles of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50,\sigma=10).$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  The equation $$\Pr[-k_1 < Z < k_2] = 0.5$$ implies $0 < k_1 < k_2$.  Then if we want the central $50\%$ probability mass, $k_1 = k_2 = k > 0$; consequently, $$\Pr[Z < k] = \Pr[Z \le 0] + \Pr[0 < Z < k] = \frac{1}{2} + \Pr[0 < Z < k] > \frac{1}{2}.$$  What is intended is either $$2 \Pr[Z < k] - 1 = 0.5,$$ or $$2 \Pr[Z < -k] = 0.5.$$